# How to determine if two side effects on a assignment are unsequenced?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++17, partial-ordering

From [§5.2.6/1](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.post.incr#1) we have (emphasis is mine):

> The value of a postfix ++ expression is the value of its operand. [
>   Note: the value obtained is a copy of the original value  — end note ]
>   The operand shall be a modifiable lvalue. The type of the operand
>   shall be an arithmetic type other than cv bool, or a pointer to a
>   complete object type. The value of the operand object is modified by
>   adding 1 to it. **The value computation of the ++ expression is
>   sequenced before the modification of the operand object**. With
>   respect to an indeterminately-sequenced function call, the operation
>   of postfix ++ is a single evaluation. [ Note: Therefore, a function
>   call shall not intervene between the lvalue-to-rvalue conversion and
>   the side effect associated with any single postfix ++ operator.  — end
>   note ] The result is a prvalue. The type of the result is the
>   cv-unqualified version of the type of the operand. If the operand is a
>   bit-field that cannot represent the incremented value, the resulting
>   value of the bit-field is implementation-defined. See also [expr.add]
>   and [expr.ass].

That is, the modification of the operand object is **sequenced after** the value computation of the `++` expression.

From [§5.18/1](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.ass#1) we have (emphasis is mine):

> The assignment operator (=) and the compound assignment operators all
>   group right-to-left. All require a modifiable lvalue as their left
>   operand and return an lvalue referring to the left operand. The result
>   in all cases is a bit-field if the left operand is a bit-field. In all
>   cases, **the assignment is sequenced after the value computation of
>   the right and left operands**, and before the value computation of the
>   assignment expression. With respect to an indeterminately-sequenced
>   function call, the operation of a compound assignment is a single
>   evaluation. [ Note: Therefore, a function call shall not intervene
>   between the lvalue-to-rvalue conversion and the side effect associated
>   with any single compound assignment operator.  — end note ]
>
> *assignment-expression*:
>             *conditional-expression*
>             *logical-or-expression* *assignment-operator* *initializer-clause*
>             *throw-expression*
>
> *assignment-operator*: one of
>             =  *=  /=  %=   +=  -=  >>=  <<=  &=  ^=  |=

The assignment is also **sequenced after** the value computation of the right and left operands of the assignment operator.

Thus, if we consider the expression

```
i = i++;
```

we know from §5.2.6/1 that the side effect of the expression `i++`, on the RHS of this assignment expression is sequenced after the value computation of `i++`. And from §5.18/1 we know that the side effect corresponding to the assignment to `i` on the LHS of the assignment operator is sequenced after the value computation of the right and left operands of the assignment operator.

But how do I show that these two side effects are unsequenced, in order to prove that the expression `i = i++;` shows undefined behavior?

Comment: Have you read [Undefined behavior and sequence points](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4176328/undefined-behavior-and-sequence-points)?

Comment: I did, but couldn't find the answer there.

Comment: Start reading at *Now the Standard in §5/4 says* under the section **What is the relation between Undefined Behaviour and Sequence Points?**

Comment: I tagged the question with `C++1z`

Comment: Note that not a word is said about the relative ordering of the incrementation and the assignment – all you know is that they are both sequenced after the value computation of `i++`.

Comment: @molbdnilo I agree with this. But the absence of a relative ordering doesn't allow me, I think, to conclude that the alluded side effects are unsequenced.

Comment: @Belloc That's what unsequenced means. Read [intro.exec](http://eel.is/c++draft/intro.execution#15).

Comment: @molbdnilo I can't find anything in [intro.execution]/15 (http://eel.is/c++draft/intro.execution#15) that would allow me to verify that the two side effects mentioned above are unsequenced.

Comment: Oops, should have been [13](http://eel.is/c++draft/intro.execution#13), not 15.

Comment: @molbdnilo You were the one who said above `Note that not a word is said about the relative ordering of the incrementation and the assignment`. If I don't know anything about the ordering of those two side effects, how should I use [intro.execution]/13 to certify that these side effects are unsequenced?

Comment: What exactly is unclear about "If A is not sequenced before B and B is not sequenced before A, then A and B are unsequenced."?

Comment: I don't know whether A is sequence before or after B. So I can't say whether A is not sequence before B, nor whether B is not sequenced before A.

Answer (score 8):

First, if A is not sequenced before B and B is not sequenced before A, then A and B are *unsequenced* (1.9/13). That's the **definition** of unsequenced. Second, if two side effects on a scalar object are unsequenced, the behavior is undefined (1.9/15). So unless you can find something that says that the post-increment and the assignment are sequenced (and you won't), the behavior is undefined.

Comment: `So unless you can find something that says that the post-increment and the assignment are sequenced (and you won't), the behavior is undefined` I don't agree with that. Again, the fact that the Standard doesn't say anything about the relative ordering of those side-effects, doesn't allow me, I think, to conclude that they are unsequenced.

Comment: @Belloc - where do you expect to find a statement that they're sequenced if not in the standard? Keep in mind that the definition of undefined behavior applies to constructs for which the standard does not impose any requirements. Unless you can find a requirement that one of these is sequenced before the other, the behavior is undefined.

Comment: I wasn't expecting any statement in the Standard that they are sequenced, but that they are **unsequenced**. In reference to undefined behavior, [intro.execution]/15 is quite clear: `If a side effect on a scalar object is unsequenced relative to either another side effect on the same scalar object or a value computation using the value of the same scalar object, and they are not potentially concurrent ([intro.multithread]), the behavior is undefined`. That is, first we must prove that the side effects are unsequenced, before we can say anything about UB.

Comment: @Belloc The standard only specifies which operations are sequenced, and how. Which things are *un*sequenced follows from that by the definition above.

Comment: @molbdnilo `The standard only specifies which operations are sequenced` Incorrect. [intro.execution/15](http://eel.is/c++draft/intro.execution#15) starts with this `Except where noted, evaluations of operands of individual operators and of subexpressions of individual expressions are unsequenced.`

Comment: Re: "the standard does not impose any requirements": not a C++ expert, but I guess that the Standard requires for the side effects to be (eventually) applied. Is that correct? If so, then this is at least one requirement. Hence, it is not "does not impose any requirements".